# Error de sintax en token else

Tags: java

Aquí esta mi implementación del programa solicitado:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Nombre = "";

        System.out.println("********************************************************");
        System.out.println("*Bienvenido al sistema vacacional de Coca-Cola Companny*");
        System.out.println("********************************************************");

        float Antigüedad = 0;
        int Clave = 0;

        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");
        Nombre = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su clave de identificación: ");
        Clave = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su tiempo de servicio: ");
        Antigüedad = in.nextInt();

        in.close();

        if (Clave == 1){
            
            if (Antigüedad == 1 && Antigüedad < 2)

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 6 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antigüedad >= 2 && Antigüedad <=6) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 14 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antigüedad >= 7) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 20 días de vacaciones");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted todavia no tiene derecho a un periódo vacacional");

        } else if(Clave == 2) {

            if(Antigüedad == 1 && Antigüedad < 2);

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 7 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antigüedad >= 2 && Antigüedad <=6) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 15 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antigüedad >= 7) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 22 días de vacaciones");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted todavia no tiene derecho a un periódo vacacional");

        } else if(Clave == 3) {

            if(Antigüedad == 1 && Antigüedad < 2);

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 10 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antigüedad >= 2 && Antigüedad <=6) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 20 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antigüedad >= 7) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 30 días de vacaciones");

        } else {

            System.out.print("Hola " + Nombre + "Usted todavia no tiene derecho a un periódo vacacional");

        } 
    }
}
```

Pero al compilar el programa recibo el siguiente mensaje:

***Syntax error on token "else", delete this token***

Hay errores ubicados en [45, 11] y [63, 11]

Estoy usando Visual Studio Code 1.47.0

Comment: No lo había revisado, muchas gracias por decirme

Comment: no falta ningún corchete, pero revisa lo que describo en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente debes recordar que las convenciones acerca del nombramiento de variables indican que debemos evitar usar en las variables, caracteres acentuados. Aunque estrictamente se permita en algunos casos, esto puede causar problemas con la codificación de caracteres, incluso en algún IDE puedes tener algo de problemas.

Por esta razón te sugiero renombrar la variable `Antigüedad` por `Antiguedad`

Principalmente tienes otro detalle importante, dentro de tu estructura `if` debes agregar primeramente los `else if` y finalmente el  `else` que indicaría en este caso que el usuario no tiene periodo de vacaciones.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Nombre = "";

        System.out.println("********************************************************");
        System.out.println("*Bienvenido al sistema vacacional de Coca-Cola Companny*");
        System.out.println("********************************************************");

        float Antiguedad = 0;
        int Clave = 0;

        System.out.println("Introduzca su nombre: ");
        Nombre = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su clave de identificación: ");
        Clave = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca su tiempo de servicio: ");
        Antiguedad = in.nextInt();

        in.close();

        if (Clave == 1){
            
            if (Antiguedad == 1 && Antiguedad < 2)

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 6 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antiguedad >= 2 && Antiguedad <=6) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 14 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antiguedad >= 7) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 20 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Clave == 2) {

            if(Antiguedad == 1 && Antiguedad < 2);

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 7 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antiguedad >= 2 && Antiguedad <=6) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 15 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antiguedad >= 7) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 22 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Clave == 3) {

            if(Antiguedad == 1 && Antiguedad < 2);

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 10 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antiguedad >= 2 && Antiguedad <=6) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 20 días de vacaciones");

        } else if(Antiguedad >= 7) {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted tiene 30 días de vacaciones");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Hola " + Nombre + ", usted todavia no tiene derecho a un periódo vacacional");

        }     
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)